# Concatenate anything in C ansi

Tags: c, string, concatenation, function-pointers, void-pointers

I need to create a C-function to concatenate two of any type of data and return the string that is the result of concatenation. I have done this function below, but it does not work. Could somebody help me?

```
// void pointer does not store value, is just the address of a memory location
char* concatenate(void* varA, int tamA, void* varB, int tamB)
{
    // char is 1 byte
    char* result;
    char* a,b; // helpers
    result = malloc((tamA+tamB)*sizeof(char)); 

    a = varA; // "a" receives the address pointed to by the pointer varA
    b = varB; // "b" receives the address pointed to by the pointer varB
    *result = *result << tamA + *a;
    *result = *result << tamB + *b;
    result = a;    // let the results point to "a"
    return result; // the result is the pointer "a"
}
```

Comment: That really isn't C, using the `<<` operator for strings is C++.

Comment: If you are compiling this in `C`, then `*result = *result << tamA + *a;` will replace the character pointed to by `*result` with its original value, shifted left by `tamA` bits, and the value of `*a` added to it. Also, the declaration `char* a,b;` is wrong. It shoudl be `char *a, *b;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is copy the data that `varA` and `varB` point to into a new memory buffer, one after the other, and return a char-pointer to this buffer. You can achieve this easily with the `memcpy` function.

```
char *concatenate(void *varA, int tamA, void *varB, int tamB)
{
    char* result = malloc(tamA + tamB); 

    // copy varA to "result"
    memcpy(result, varA, tamA);
    // copy varB to "result" after varA
    memcpy(result+tamA, varB, tamB);

    return result;
}
```

Note that whatever data `varA` and `varB` hold it is used as is and not converted to a human readable representation.

Answer (score 3):

In C, which is what you're asking about even though your code is C++, you can't do it like that.

There's no way to figure out from a bare `void *` how to convert it to a string.

You must add type information of some form, such as `printf()`'s string using e.g. `%d` for decimal integers and so on.

This would be a workable prototype, I think:

```
char * concat_any(const char *format1, const void *data1,
                  const char *format2, const void *data2);
```

I'm not saying "optimal" or even "suitable", but it would at least be possible to implement to that prototype. The `format` strings could be `printf()`-style, or whatever.

Note that for C, this would also be *very impractical*, since taking a `void *` implies that you need a pointer to the data, always. If you wanted to e.g. concatenate two numbers, you couldn't do it like this:

```
char *fortytwo = concat_any("%d", 4, "%d", 2);  /* BROKEN CODE */
```

since that passes integers instead of `void *`, which is very ugly. You would have to do it like this:

```
const int four = 4, two = 2;
const char *fortytwo = concat_any("%d", &four, "%d", &two);
```

which is clearly not exactly convenient.

So, it would be better to use varargs, but then you get the problem of not being able to associate different varargs with different non-variable arguments, like so:

```
char * concat_anyv(const char *format1, ...,
                   const char *format2, ...);   /* BROKEN CODE */
```

So, how about having two formatting strings first, then trusting the caller to pass the two arguments as varargs? That would give:

```
char * concat_anyv2(const char *format1, const char *format2, ...);
```

Now we're talking. This can be trivially implemented, even: internally concatenate the two formatting strings, and call [`vsnprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vsprintf) two times: once to figure out buffer size, then allocate, and call it again.

Usage would be like so:

```
char *fortytwo = concat_anyv2("%d", "%d", 4, 2);
```

Done.

Comment: Now the question is, why would anyone want to do this in production?

Answer (score 0):

I have two little string functions in C that I use.  The first is an adaptation others have made that uses the **printf** model as others mentioned, you have to know what the data types are going in:

```
char* str(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  int size;
  char *buff;
  va_list argp1;
  va_list argp2;

  va_start(argp1, fmt);
  va_copy(argp2, argp1);

  //calling vsnprintf with a NULL buffer simply returns what would
  //be the size of the resulting string but does not include space for nul byte
  size = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, argp1) + 1;  
  va_end(argp1);

  //now actually allocate a buffer of the correct size and then fill it
  buff = calloc(1,size);
  assert(buff != NULL);
  vsnprintf(buff, size, fmt, argp2);
  va_end(argp2);

  return buff;
}
```

With this I can *concat* doing a simple

```
char *d = str("%s%s%d", s1, s2, 25);
```

I just have to remember to free the string that is returned as it is allocated memory.

I have a second routine that I use for simple *string* concatenations that I can nest in other calls as it does internal cleanup for me:

```
typedef enum {FREE_NONE, FREE_ONE, FREE_TWO, FREE_BOTH} CONCAT_FREE_FLAG;
char *concat(char *one, char *two, CONCAT_FREE_FLAG f)
{
  int size = strlen(one) + strlen(two) + 1;
  char *buff = calloc(1,size);
  assert(buff != NULL);
  strcpy(buff, one);
  strcat(buff, two);

  if( f == FREE_ONE || f == FREE_BOTH)
    free(one);
  if( f == FREE_TWO || f == FREE_BOTH)
    free(two);
  return buff;
}
```

This allows me to do things like:

```
 char *s = concat(
              concat("Static ",str("%dx%d", x, y), FREE_TWO),
              "Other Static", FREE_ONE);
```

The reason I have this is really syntactic sugar so I can pass dynamically allocated strings in, get a new dynamically allocated string but not have to worry about cleaning up the input strings.